# How do I run Worms: World Party on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, worms-world-party

Can anyone get the game Worms: World Party running on Ubuntu? If so, how?
Since that game is old, I think there has to be a way.

Comment: Its not been tested under Wine for a bit but the results are not encouraging http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3905

Comment: Instead of trying to run worms world part you should try [hedgewars](http://hedgewars.org/) which is pretty good and also has a online mode.

Answer (score 5):

If it is a CD-ROM based game that normally installs on Windows, you may be able to get it installed and working using Wine.

Wine is a program that allows the installation and operation of Windows-based applications. I have successfully used it to install and play several games, but I've also failed to get some games working.

A very popular addition to Wine is called PlayOnLinux. Both Wine and POL can be installed using Ubuntu's built-in Software Center. Look for it in the 'Applications' menu.

Good luck!